# How to test a nested context with react testing library renderHook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-testing-library

This is my test example in typescript

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

interface PropsCtx {
  input: string;
  myval: string;
  setMyVal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}
const placeholder: PropsCtx = {
  input: '',
  myval: '',
  setMyVal: (prev) => prev
};
const CTX = React.createContext<PropsCtx>(placeholder);
interface PropsProvider {
  input: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
const MyProvider: FC<PropsProvider> = ({ children, input }) => {
  const [myval, setMyVal] = useState<PropsCtx['myval']>(placeholder.myval);
  const value = useMemo<PropsCtx>(() => ({ input, myval, setMyVal }), [input, myval, setMyVal]);
  return <CTX.Provider value={value}>{children}</CTX.Provider>;
};

const Wrapper: FC<PropsProvider> = ({ input, children }) => (
  <MyProvider input={input}>{children}</MyProvider>
);

interface PropsUse {
  newinput: string;
}
const useFromProvider= ({ newinput }: PropsUse) => {
  const { input, myval, setMyVal } = React.useContext(CTX);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMyVal(newinput);
    }, 1000)
  }, []);

  return { input, myval, setMyVal };
};
describe('useFromProvider', () => {
  it('should return context results', async () => {
    const wrapper = () => <Wrapper input={'hello'}><div>content</div></Wrapper>
    const { result } = renderHook(
      () =>
        useFromProvider({newinput: 'goodbye'}),
      { wrapper }
    );

    expect((result as any).current.input).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

> Error
> result.current === undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to render the `children`, the `wrapper` option should be:

```
describe('useFromProvider', () => {
    it('should return context results', async () => {
        const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Wrapper input={'hello'}>{children}</Wrapper>;
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useFromProvider({ newinput: 'goodbye' }), { wrapper });

        expect((result as any).current.input).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```